# How to touch file names containing date greater than specific date in bash?

Tags: bash

I want to touch all the files which are having date GREATER THAN 20201009 in its name, inside specific directory recursively.

examples of input file names and its directory location

```
/tmp/data/gov/USA/NY/nyc_20201006.txt
/tmp/data/gov/USA/NY/nyc_20201008.txt
/tmp/data/gov/USA/NY/nyc_20201009.txt
/tmp/data/gov/USA/NY/nyc_20201010.txt
/tmp/data/gov/USA/NY/nyc_20201011.txt

/tmp/data/gov/USA/CA/san_mateo_20201006.txt
/tmp/data/gov/USA/CA/san_mateo_20201007.txt
/tmp/data/gov/USA/CA/san_mateo_20201008.txt
/tmp/data/gov/USA/CA/san_mateo_20201009.txt
/tmp/data/gov/USA/CA/san_mateo_20201010.txt
/tmp/data/gov/USA/CA/san_mateo_20201011.txt

/tmp/data/gov/USA/FL/tampa_bay_20201006.txt
/tmp/data/gov/USA/FL/tampa_bay_20201008.txt
/tmp/data/gov/USA/FL/tampa_bay_20201009.txt
/tmp/data/gov/USA/FL/tampa_bay_20201010.txt
/tmp/data/gov/USA/FL/tampa_bay_20201011.txt
```

Now, Inside USA directory I want to touch any file whose name is containing dt>=20201009

so the candidate files to be touched will be

```
/tmp/data/gov/USA/NY/nyc_20201010.txt
/tmp/data/gov/USA/NY/nyc_20201011.txt


/tmp/data/gov/USA/CA/san_mateo_20201010.txt
/tmp/data/gov/USA/CA/san_mateo_20201011.txt


/tmp/data/gov/USA/FL/tampa_bay_20201010.txt
/tmp/data/gov/USA/FL/tampa_bay_20201011.txt
```

Comment: You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: @praxnet : Loop through the files in question, and for each file which fulfills the condition, touch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

find /tmp/data/gov/USA -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | while IFS= read -d "" f; do
    if [[ $f =~ ([[:digit:]]{8})\.txt ]] && (( ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} > 20201009 )); then
        touch "$f"
    fi
done
```

- The `find` command searches for the specified files and prints the
  filenames delimited by a null character to preserve filenames
  which contain special characters.
- The `while` loop iterates over the filenames passed by `find`.
- The regex `([[:digit:]]{8})\.txt` matches eight consecutive digits
  followed by a suffix `.txt` assigning the shell variable `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`
  to the digits.
- The condition `(( ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} > 20201009 ))` returns true
  if the bash variable is greater than 20201009.